# Removes all items from a System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection in C#

Tags: c#

I have the following collection where I enter some values using a method:

```
 Collection<double> temp = new Collection<double>();
```

I would like to remove all the items from the collection at some point so I could be able to start filling it again from the beginning as I do the first time I initialize the program.
I tried like this but it doesn't work.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < temp.Count; i++)
        {
            temp.RemoveAt(i);
        }
```

What is wrong?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `Clear` method:

```
temp.Clear();
```

The reason why your loop doesn't work is because when you do a `RemoveAt`, the indexes of all items shift. So, say you started with this:

> 6, 2, 8, 5, 3

In the first iteration, `i` is `0`, and the first item will be removed:

> 2, 8, 5, 3

For the second iteration, `i` is `1`, but that's no-longer the next item to delete, so you get this:

> 2, 5, 3

Then, `i` is `2`, and you get this:

> 2, 5

Now `i` is `> temp.Count`. See how you can be left with leftover items?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Clear()` method -

```
temp.Clear();
```

Answer (score 1):

By calling `RemoveAt`, you are assuming there does exist an item at the given index. However, by removing it, the collection has one less item, and hence your `for` loop doesn't make sense. It won't throw an exception just because of `temp.Count` being evaluated during each iteration. In effect, it will remove only every other item from the collection.

Instead, use the [`Clear`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132405%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use indexed removal, as soon as you remove the first item, the collection gets reindexed, the second element becomes first, third becomes second etc. You will remove every odd element and get and exception after going out of the collection size. In .net implementation you would probably get an exception eariler, as soon as you remove the first item, the enumerator will complain that you can't modify the collection you are enumerating at the very moment.

There are few ways to work this around, the easiest it to clear the collection using dedicated method (Clear). In case of collection of references, you could also create a collection of copies of references from the original collection and iterate over the cloned collection but remove from the original.

Answer (score 0):

If you **really** need to remove one element at a time (rather than calling `Clear()` to remove them all in one go) then you need to iterate in reverse order:

```
int count = temp.Count;
for (int i = count-1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    temp.RemoveAt(i);
}
```

This will remove the elements from the end of the list so that your index is always within range of the remaining list and you remove all the items from the list.

Or only use the size as a counter:

```
int count = temp.Count;
for (int i = 0; i < count ; i++)
{
    temp.RemoveAt(0);
}
```

This isn't using the collections iterators at all and as you're getting the count before you start removing elements it shouldn't fail.

Something like this would only be needed if you needed to do some processing on each element etc. before removing it from the list.

Comment: Or just always remove at index 0. But the clear method is the best way.

Comment: @Wjdavis5 - good point. I've included that as an alternative.